# Creating new feature class of points on line based on m-value from another layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I have a feature class made of numerous line segments (NHD river flow line). Each line segment has its own code/ID and m-value. Then I have a feature class of points (storm water runoff points) where one of its attributes is the closest (in distance) m-measure of the closest line segment. The goal is to create a new feature class of points on the line segments based on the m-value in my stormwater feature class.

Locating features along route was the first step I've taken to get the ID of the closest line, m-value along that line for each stormwater points. My next step is to create a point at the m-value on the NHD line associated to the stormwater point. This is so I could use that point on the NHD line as a starting point for trace network analysis.

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reading the help file? Suggest you start with the [introduction to linear referencing](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/linear-referencing/introduction-to-linear-referencing.htm) and explore route events.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [Locate Features Along Routes](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/linear-referencing/locate-features-along-routes.htm) tool.

This tool will take as input your storm water runoff points and your NHD river flow line and will output a table witch locate each point along the line using three fields: one with the ID of the closest line, a second with the M value along the line and a third with the distance to the line (there is an option to keep all other fields).

Comment: That was the first step I've taken to get the ID of the closest line, m-value along that line for each stormwater points. My next step is to create a point at the m-value on the NHD line associated to the stormwater point. This is so I could use that point on the NHD line as a starting point for trace network analysis.

Will add this to the original post to be clearer.

Comment: @Hanis in the link about the tool they suggest to use make route event layer (let  offset setting blank) to display the point from the table, then you may just use the event layer as a "normal" point layer or export to feature class. Also you should follow Hornbydd suggestion and read on linear referencing....